# Grabbing video from framebuffer

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-encoding, qt, drm

Can I grab video from framebuffer using *fbdev* (old `/dev/fb0`) or *DRI* *DRM* features?

Can I use `ffmpeg` for this purposes?

Currently I want to grab output of *Qt Quick* window, running on *EGLFS* *QPA* backend (i.e. on fullscreen window, rendered by *OpenGL ES 2* and higher). I can do it frame by frame using `QScreen` capabilities, but I want to prevent aftermath of crushing or any undesired interactions between `QScreen` and `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I've tested and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [FFmpeg fbdev input device](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#fbdev):

```
ffmpeg -f fbdev -framerate 10 -i /dev/fb0 output.foo
```

If you omit `-framerate` the default value of 25 will be applied.